# C# и Json десериализация

Tags: c#, json, десериализация

Есть `Json` строка на 4 МБ. Нужно десериализировать в анонимный объект.
Пробовал `Json.Decode(s)` - возвращает `Exception` "`Длина строки превышает значение, заданное для свойства maxJsonLength`"

это понятно. попробовал `JavaScriptSerializer`. делаю так

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
allData = serializer.DeserializeObject(s);
```

и тут возникает такая проблема, что на одном компьютере все работает нормально, а на другом внезапно выбивает исключение "`Недопустимый переданный объект, ожидается имя члена`". Хотя строка вроде корректная

Позже оказалось, что существует еще и такой параметр как `MaxJsonDeserializerMembers`, который по умолчанию установлен в `1000` (чего мне, скорей всего недостаточно). В интернете полно вариантов, как увеличить его для `ASP.NET`, а у меня `dll` библиотека на `WinForms`. Пробовал так

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("MaxJsonDeserializerMembers", int.MaxValue.ToString());
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

но не помогло.

Есть какие-нибудь идеи? Может сторонняя библиотека для `json` десериализации или решение этой проблемы?

Comment: если **действительно необходимо** использовать старый и медленный  `JavaScriptSerializer`, то размер его буфера можно увеличить используя `MaxJsonLength`. см http://stackoverflow.com/a/1151993/315935. Использование альтернативного сериалайзера предпочтительней (см. ответ Павла).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посмотрите библиотеку [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) - возможно, с ней будет разобраться проще.

Увеличение же параметра `MaxJsonDeserializerMembers` что для ASP.NET, что для WinForms выглядит одинаково, отличается лишь имя файла конфигурации.

Comment: а не подскажете для общего развития, как это сделать в WinForms в общем случае? какой файл править? http://joxi.ru/D2P6aQbIdBzkNr

Comment: Править нужно файл `app.config`. Если его нет - создайте.